# Accessing ExtendedData information via Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml

I have a KML file which contains within each `<Placemark>` node an `<ExtendedData>` node, and then a number of `<Data>` nodes with key/value pairs. I've followed the examples at: *http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/extendeddata.html* and *code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps.html* suggests maps do support KML ExtendedData nodes (albeit partially), but I cannot find a way of accessing the ExtendedData object via javascript. I'm using:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(agency_layer, 'click', function(kmlEvent) {
  console.debug( kmlEvent );
}
```

(where agency_layer is the KML object).
kmlEvent contains all of the KML feature data, but not the extendedData, and i'm scratching my head. I want to make my KML semantically sensible, rather than loading more data into the description and parsing it later with javascript.

has anyone had a similar experience, or knows how to access ExtendedData nodes via Google Maps API v3?

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the exact same thing. I constructed a jQuery solution from the information I found [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/xml-parsing-with-jquery).

Since jQuery can parse xml easily, and kml is xml, it works out pretty well. Here's the function I wrote.

```
function extendedDataToArray(feature)
{
    var returnArray = new Array();
    $(feature.getKml()).find("Data").each(function()
    {
        returnArray[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).find("value").text();
    }
    );
    return returnArray;
}
```

The function returns an associative array with keys equal to the names of your data elements, and values as the content of your value tags. Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the suggestion of parsing the KML using JQuery, the problem is that the ExtendedData nodes are stripped out when loading it through the Google Maps API, so I cannot even see that data. I've ended up accessing the KML directly (similar to this) and dropping each pin manually, rather than using the KML feature within the Google Maps API :(

Comment: That's really unfortunate :/. I'm working in the Google Earth API, and so far it's kept the kml intact for each Placemark.

Comment: +1 By the way, JavaScript does not have Associative Arrays. You should declare the `returnArray` as an object `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution might to pass data in the placemark description and preprocess description when it needs to be used.

```
/*
<Placemark>
    <name></name>
    <description><![CDATA[
    Lorem Ipsum  [data]{"datakey":524}[/data]
    ]]>
    </description>
    <Point>
        <coordinates>COORDINATES</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>
*/
   var map_overlay = new google.maps.KmlLayer(
        'URL_TO_KML_FILE',
        {
            'suppressInfoWindows': true
        }
    );
    map_overlay.setMap( gmap );

    var placemarkInfo = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    google.maps.event.addListener(map_overlay, 'click', function (kmlEvent) {

        var text_to_process = kmlEvent.featureData.description,
        matches = text_to_process.match(/\[data\](.*)\[\/data\]/),
        json_data_string = matches[1],
        json_data = JSON.parse(json_data_string),
        real_description = text_to_process.split('[data]')[0];

        alert(json_data.datakey);

        placemarkInfo.setContent( real_description );
        placemarkInfo.setPosition(kmlEvent.latLng);
        placemarkInfo.open(gmap);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the same thing. You can see what data is being returned by using the `JSON.stringify()` function on the `kmlEvent` object:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(kmlEvent));
```

`ExtendedData` nodes are partially supported according to the [KML Elements Supported in Google Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps.html) page but I have yet to figure out how to properly use them.

Comment: yeah, it says "untyped <Data> only" is supported for ExtendedData, but I can't seem to find it in the object.

Answer (score 0):

Certain Data is stripped from the ExtendedData, but you can use the `getBalloonHtml()` or `getBalloonHtmlUnsafe()` if you trust the source of the KML. See 'https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/extendeddata' for reference.