# Get ExtendedData from KML with Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml

I have a KML export from google maps, and some pointers have images or youtube videos. When i open the kml i see a tag  on some pointers with youtube and image links. But when i load them into the Google Maps Api i cant see these urls.

This is what i have:

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: { lat: 52.448346, lng: 4.602585},
      zoom: 12
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
    var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: 'test_1.kml',
        clickable: true,
        preserveViewport: true,
        map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'click', function(event) {
        console.debug(event);
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Is there something to extract the media from the pointers?

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be to export to a xml or json then build a map from it since ExtendedData of kml is partially supported by design, check out the [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps?csw=1)

Here a possible duplicate of this question: [Accessing ExtendedData information via Google Maps API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578141/accessing-extendeddata-information-via-google-maps-api-v3)