# How to display image from my kml file onto a Google map in a sidebar

Tags: google-maps, kml

I am editing my question after spending 3 days unable to figure this out:
I have had a website of all stairs in Seattle that showed a description and image when a marker was clicked.  It has been working well for a couple of years.
(http://seattlestairs.home.comcast.net/~seattlestairs)

Then google changed the format of their kml files and if I substitute the NEW kml for the OLD one, I no longer can see the image.  You can see this at:
(http://seattlestairs.home.comcast.net/~seattlestairs/index2.html)

However, if I just embed my map into a webpage and click on the marker, the info window pops up and shows the image and description.

However, I don't like that because the images are too small to see details.
I want my sidebar images back and was hoping somebody could tell me how to change the code to make that happen.  (I am just an amateur programmer).  The comments suggested using a parser and I am able to get the gist of that but I can not figure out exactly how to do it.

Here is the structure of a placemark in the OLD kml file:

```
<Placemark>
    <name>#176 John St</name>
    <description><![CDATA[<div ><img style="width:400px" src="http://lh6.ggpht.com/_izunqcjpHto/TIx-yqN7PdI/AAAAAAAADXw/lt7xzoZ1ivI/s720/%23176%20side.jpg"><br>67 steps</div>]]></description>
    <styleUrl>#ordinary</styleUrl>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-122.282104,47.618984,0.000000</coordinates>
    </Point>
```

Here it is in the NEW kml file:

```
<Placemark>
                <styleUrl>#icon-ci-1</styleUrl>
                <name>#176 John St</name>
                <ExtendedData>
                    <Data name='gx_media_links'>
                        <value>http://lh6.ggpht.com/_izunqcjpHto/TIx-yqN7PdI/AAAAAAAADXw/lt7xzoZ1ivI/s720/%23176%20side.jpg</value>
                    </Data>
                </ExtendedData>
                <description><![CDATA[67 steps]]></description>
                <Point>
                    <coordinates>-122.282104,47.618984,0.0</coordinates>
                </Point>
        </Placemark>
```

I previously used a sample java script to do this and just put the "description" into the infowindow.  Now with the new kml files the source of the image is in a "extended data" and I don't know the right way to access that image information.  I can get the name and description but not the image.

My old script looked like this:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     function initialize() {
       var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(47.605, -122.333);
       var myOptions = {
         zoom: 12,
        center: latlng,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                               myOptions);
     var stairLayer = new    google.maps.KmlLayer('http://seattlestairs.home.comcast.net/~seattlestairs/SeattleStairs97.kml', 
     {preserveViewport: true, suppressInfoWindows:true});

 stairLayer.setMap(map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(stairLayer, 'click', function(kmlEvent) {
    var text = kmlEvent.featureData.description;
    text = kmlEvent.featureData.name  + text;
    showInContentWindow(text);
  });
  function showInContentWindow(text) {
    var sidediv = document.getElementById('content_window');
    sidediv.innerHTML = text;
  } 
 }
</script>
```

So where is said "text = kmlEvent.featureData.description"  there needs to be some code that will allow me to get the src of the image, and then to put that into html into the sidediv, but I don't know how.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. KmlLayer does not let you access any of the data from the KML except on a click.  If you use a 3rd party KML parser (like [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) or [geoxml-v3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/)) you can use whatever information you want from the KML ([one example which puts the marker icons in the sidebar](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_icon_linkto.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/visualisationmagazine_com_lacreativemap_kml.xml))

Comment: When the user clicks on an icon, the sidebar does show the name of the stairway and some text about the number of steps.  It just does not show the image, that is what I am trying to get.

Comment: You didn't post the HTML required for your code, so I didn't see that.  However, that said, [I don't see a problem with the posted code (once I add a div with id='content_window')](http://jsfiddle.net/uwvja3mz/1/) (I see the pictures in that div).

Comment: oops, sorry, I mistyped the address of the web page.  It works now because I still have a copy of the old klm, but now Google has a new format for klm files and if I export a new map with the new klm then I can't get the image to show up.  I am also puzzled because their sample script used klmEvent.featureData  but there is no "feature" anywhere in the klm file that I see, so this is something that is not very obvious, it must be something about the way Google maps set up the kml in the first place.

Comment: What does the new KML look like (I was wondering, I didn't see any ExtendedData tags in the KML you have in your posted code)?  Why do you need to use the KML exported from Google Maps?  If you do need to use that, you can (as I said in my comment earlier) use a third party parser to get that data.

Comment: Hi, I edited my initial question to include the structure of both the old and the new google map kml structure.  The code works fine with the old structure but not with the new one.  It seems there should be some simple way to just get that src link but I can't find any info about it for the new kml files.

Comment: Where is the new KML?

Comment: related question: [Accessing ExtendedData information via Google Maps API v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578141/accessing-extendeddata-information-via-google-maps-api-v3)

Answer (score 0):

[KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer) ([API Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#KmlLayer)) does not let you access any of the data from the KML except on a click. If you use a 3rd party KML parser (like geoxml3 or geoxml-v3) you can use whatever information you want from the KML
One option is to use a third party parser (like the KMZ branch of [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/)) which allows you to access the `<ExtendedData>` in the KML.

```
var map;
var geoXmlDoc;

function initialize() {
   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(47.605, -122.333);
   var myOptions = {
     zoom: 12,
     center: latlng,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                               myOptions);

   var myParser = new geoXML3.parser({
                        map:map,
                        afterParse: useTheData,
                        suppressInfoWindows: true,
                        suppressDirections: true
                      });
   google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
     for (var i = 0; i < geoXmlDoc.placemarks.length; i++) {
       var placemark = geoXmlDoc.placemarks[i];
       if (placemark.marker) {
         createClickableMarker(placemark);
       }
     }
   });
   myParser.parse("http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/newSeattleStairs.kml");
}
function showInContentWindow(text) {
  var sidediv = document.getElementById('content_window');
  sidediv.innerHTML = text;
} 

function createClickableMarker(placemark) {
 google.maps.event.addListener(placemark.marker,'click',function(e){
   var htmlString =placemark.name+"<br>"+placemark.description;
   var media_imgs = placemark.vars.val.gx_media_links.split(" ");
   for (var i=0; i < media_imgs.length; i++) {
     htmlString += "<br><img src='"+placemark.vars.val.gx_media_links+"' width='400'/>";
   }
   showInContentWindow(htmlString)
 });
}

function useTheData(doc){
  geoXmlDoc = doc[0];
};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

[proof of concept](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_clickEvent.html) (there seem to be issues with the click targets for the icons, but it can be made to work).  Note that third party parsers render the KML as native Google Maps Javascript API v3 objects, so will not have the performance of the tile based rendering of KmlLayer.

Answer (score 0):

This way works on Chrome and Firefox and Safari, can't tell about IE:
I altered the kml file from Google Maps into an xml file by deleting the "kml" tags and icon info, and I read about xml path from the W3 online teaching, and then modified their example.

So, first I used the Google-maps event feature to get the name of the stairway.
Then I loaded the xml file and used the "evaluate" function to get the source for my images (called value" in the kml file):

```
        <script>
var smoname = " ";
var smodev = " ";

// this will set up the google map in the right location
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(47.605, -122.333);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: myLatlng
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

//Here is the raw kml file as exported from google maps
  var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://seattlestairs.home.comcast.net/~seattlestairs/newSeattleStairs.kml',
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    map: map
  });

 google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'click', function(kmlEvent) {

//gets the name of the stairway when the icon is clicked
   smoname = kmlEvent.featureData.name;
   smodef = kmlEvent.featureData.description;

   smoin = smoname +"<br>"+ smodef;

 showInContentWindow(smoin);

//looks up the url of the image from the name 
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
try {xhttp.responseType="msxml-document"} catch(err) {} // Helping IE
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp;
}

var x=loadXMLDoc("AllSeattleStairs.xml");
var xml=x.responseXML;
path="/Document/Placemark[name= '" + smoname + "']/ExtendedData/Data/value";

// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType=="msxml-document")
{
xml.setProperty("SelectionLanguage","XPath");
nodes=xml.selectNodes(path);
document.getElementById("showme").innerHTML = "<img width = 400px src =' " + nodes.childNodes[0].nodeValue + " ' ></src>";}

// code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
{
var nodes=xml.evaluate(path, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
var result=nodes.iterateNext();

document.getElementById("showme").innerHTML = "<img width = 400px src =' " + result.childNodes[0].nodeValue + " ' ></src>";

}
      });

function showInContentWindow(smoin) {
    var sidediv = document.getElementById('content-window');
    sidediv.innerHTML = smoin;  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

   </script>
```